# Return value of SessionHandlerInterface methods in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to understand PHP session handlers and more precisely the return value of `SessionHandlerInterface::read`.

[The doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.read.php) states (emphasis mine):

> Returns an encoded string of the read data. **If nothing was read, it must return false**. Note this value is returned internally to PHP for processing.

However, the example used in [the documentation of the SessionHandler class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler) and other implementation (for instance Symfony's [PdoSessionHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/c71c8727cc665c9e9b56e299fcfcc0adfbf02bac/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php#L638)) seem to return an empty string when nothing can be read (like for instance the very first time you connect to an host).

To illustrate this, I wrote a simple test (the class inherits from `SessionHandler` instead of implementing the whole `SessionHandlerInterface` for the sake of simplicity - I know this is not recommended and the example is useless: it's just here to show the problem):

```php
<?php

define('RETURN_VALUE', false);

class SimpleSessionHandler extends SessionHandler
{
    public function read($id)
    {
        $data = parent::read($id);

        if (!$data) {
            return RETURN_VALUE;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}

$handler = new SimpleSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
$res = session_start();
print_r($res);
echo("Done");
```

When using `false` as the return value, I get a PHP error (`Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data`) while when I use `''` (empty string) it works like a charm.

I'm missing something ?

I'm using PHP 7.4.20 under Fedora 33.

Comment: The [docs of SessionHandler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) also say: "Warning
This class is designed to expose the current internal PHP session save handler, if you want to write your own custom save handlers, please **implement** the **SessionHandlerInterface** interface instead of extending from SessionHandler". However I don't see any need to return your own values, you could also `return parent::read($id);`

Comment: Besides my first comment, I come to the conclusion that it makes no sense to inherit the class and to adopt the overwritten method one-to-one. So your SimpleSessionHandler class doesn't make any sense in its current format. There are other reasons why one needs to have a custom session handler, e.g. when storing sessions in the database.

Comment: As I said, the example is for the sake of illustration: it does nothing useful and I choose to inherit from `SessionHandler` despite what the doc says for simplicity (otherwise, the code would be 5 times longer). It is a simplified version of an attempt based on `SessionHandlerInterface` to show the issue. I will state it more clearly.

Comment: As stated, `If nothing was read, it must return false` from this I assume it means, if session file is not opened or file is not readable or throwing any error/exception in such cases `read` method should return false, but if file is open and is readable but is empty, then it should return `empty` string rather than `false`

Comment: This is what I expected but the problem is that the very first you connect, the session file doesn't exist. So following the doc, we should return `false` but in that case, PHP won't open the session.

Comment: `session_start()` method creates the session file via its `open` method if doesn't exists which is then followed by `read` method so it will return `false` only when there is any error/exception while reading or creating the file.

Comment: If I'm correct, `open()` has no access to the session id so I don't see how it could create the file for this session. If you look at [the SessionHandlerInterface example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php), `open()` only ensure that the directory where to store sessions is created.

Comment: See the thread [here](https://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=162445714526464&w=2): IIUC, `read` should try to read the data if it exists or return an empty string if it doesn't; it should return `false` only when it **can't** read the data (for example if the session file cannot not created, if the DB can't be reached, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on PHP mailing list (see the thread [here](https://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=162445714526464&w=2)).

From what I understood, `read()` should try to read the data if it exists or return an empty string if it doesn't; it should return false only when it **can't** read the data (for example if the session file cannot not be created or read, if the DB can't be reached, etc.).

In the case of a session handler based on some DB it would be something like this:

```php
<?php

class DBSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    public function read($id)
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->get_session_from_db();
            if (len($data) > 0) {
                // Return data
                $this->serialize($data);
            } else {
                // Create new empty session here
                try {
                    $this->create_empty_session_in_db();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    return false;
                }
                return '';
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess that most handlers would delay the insertion in `write()` though.